# How can I filter with prefetch_related table count in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, orm

```
content = Content.objects.filter(Q(**query) | Q(**query2)).
    prefetch_related('like').all() 

return content
```

Hello.
I want to return content which has more than 10 like.
How can I do thtis?

Answer (score 0):

You do *not* need to `prefetch_related(…)` at all, you need to [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the number of likes. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Count

content = Content.objects.annotate(
    nlikes=Count('likes')
).filter(nlikes__gt=10)
```

you can also order content by the number of likes in descending order with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

content = Content.objects.annotate(
    nlikes=Count('likes')
).filter(nlikes__gt=10).order_by('-nlikes')
```